# Copy a Cell Below A Cell with a Constant Value (see screenshot) - excel

Tags: macos, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

The picture will make it all make sense. But I'm just trying to copy the text from below the "Author information:" Cell to another cell location. This isn't difficult for a few because it's just a simple copy and paste but I need to search the entire worksheet and extract all of the info from the first cell below "Author information:" At this point there are thousands of entries...

Screenshot Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbyg8lkay3c5c9s/Screenshot%202013-12-27%2016.32.38.png

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Do you know how to use VBA? run a loop looking for the cell value "Author Information:", add one onto it value when found, copy that cells value and continue until the end of the loop. Press F11 and go from there

Comment: It is quite clear what the OP is asking. The hold should be removed.

Comment: @teylyn, the question is clear but it shows no effort (if a VBA solution is required).

Comment: @brettdj, Fine, but if it's to be closed then it should be closed for the right reasons, and not because 4 people clicked "me too" on an "unclear" flag. Merry X, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

For ease, try the following.

1. In cell C2 type this formula =IF(A1="Author Information:",A2,"")
2. Copy this formula all the way down
3. copy the results in column C to another sheet and paste-special with values only
4. Sort that sheet to get rid of blanks

That should be a quick and dirty way to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub copyAuthorInfo()
Dim src As Worksheet, tgt As Worksheet
Dim irows As Long
Dim rrows As Long

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' this is the sheet with the original data
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' author info will be copied into this sheet

irows = src.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' count the number of used rows in sheet 1
rrows = 1 'row counter for the target sheet

For i = 1 To irows
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Author information:" Then 'make sure to adjust the search text
        ' copying columns A to C. Change the 3 in the following line to copy more columns.
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 3)).Copy tgt.Range("A" & rrows)
        rrows = rrows + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

To run the code, you need to open the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) with Alt-F11 or your preferred method. Use Insert > Module and paste the code. You can run the code by hitting F5 while the cursor is somewhere in the code.

You have tagged with OSX. Does that mean you use a Mac? You also tagged with Excel 2007 and 2010. The code will run fine in these, but not in Excel 2008 for Mac, because it does not support VBA.